# I would like to use two BMS's on a single pack

Tags: bms, lithium

I would like to use TWO BMS's on a single lithium pack. putting them in parallel. Q is - do i need to also run separate balance wires to each BMS , OR, just run the 2nd separate B- input to the 2nd board and let the dual boards Mosfets increase the discharge rate. ?

Comment: Why use two BMS boards instead of one that handles the job properly? We also don't know which boards you intend to use a what do their manuals say if the balance wires are required when paralleling with another BMS.

Comment: 'I would like to use two BMS' - why, what's the problem with one that you're trying to solve?